# I have a problem with showing local notifications and suddenly closing the application

Tags: flutter, dart

**I added local notifications and I added them when I click on the theme change so that it appears to me when the theme changes notification directly
And when I typed these codes, I clicked to change the theme and then it appears to me to close the application or wait, and then the emulator is disconnected without showing me any error**
I/Process ( 5214): Sending signal. PID: 5214 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

[image]
***mian.dart***

```
void main() async{

  runApp(const MyApp());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //NotifyHelper().initializeNotification();

}
```

***homepage.dart***

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late NotifyHelper notifyHelper ;
@override
  void initState() {
 notifyHelper = NotifyHelper() ;
 notifyHelper.initializeNotification() ;
 notifyHelper.requestIOSPermissions() ;
  super.initState();
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final  MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context) ;
    final orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              Get.to(NotificationScreen(
                payload: 'notification title |notification Des |23-12-2021',
              ));
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Get.isDarkMode
                ? Icons.dark_mode_outlined
                : Icons.light_mode_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              notifyHelper.displayNotification(title: 'Theme Changed', body: 'good');
              notifyHelper.scheduledNotifications();
              ThemeService().switchTheme();
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
        ],
```

***notification_services***

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:todo/ui/pages/notification_screen.dart';

class NotifyHelper {


  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  initializeNotification( ) async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    // tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('notes-med');
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
    IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize

      (initializationSettings,onSelectNotification:(String? payload) async{
      selectNotification(payload!) ;
    });
  }

  requestIOSPermissions(){
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.requestPermissions(
      alert: true ,
      badge: true ,
      sound: true ,
    );
  }

  displayNotification({required title , required String body}) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');
    IOSNotificationDetails iosPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    IOSNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics , iOS: iosPlatformChannelSpecifics );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show

      (0,title,body , platformChannelSpecifics, payload : 'Default_Sound'
    );
  }

  void selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    await Get.to(NotificationScreen(payload: payload)) ;
  }

  scheduledNotifications( )async{

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your channel id', 'your channel name',
                channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }

//older ios
  void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(int id, String? title, String? body,
      String? payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
    Get.dialog(Text(body!));
  }
}
```

***Error after click btn***

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4308)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5214):    ... 9 more
I/Process ( 5214): Sending signal. PID: 5214 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: I guess your main.dart is not complete

Comment: what should I do ?